# ASP.net MVC.2 how to define a collection of multiple types in repository interface

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, interface, repository, viewmodel

Im trying to return a list to a display template containing data from two tables, i am using the repository pattern, and a viewmodel to pass the data to the view from a LINQ query that returns both objects

is there to define a collection of multiple types in the interface?
For a single type i have used this in the interface,

```
    IQueryable<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; }
```

then i have my linq query in the repository

```
public IQueryable<CustomerSite> CustomerSites
    {
        get { return customerSitesTable; }
    }
```

However since this new query will contain 2 types, both customers and customer sites, how should this collection be defined in the interface?

======UPDATE

I have tried using the .Include (this throws an error stating that there is no definition for include in the Customer entity, not sure if im missing a name space for this?)

I have also tried creating a custom interface,

```
public interface ICustomersAndSitesRepository
{
    IQueryable<CustomerSite> CustomerSites { get; }
    IQueryable<Customer> Customers { get; }
    IQueryable<ICustomersAndSitesRepository> CustomerAndSites { get; }
}
```

And this method in the repository

```
public IQueryable <ICustomersAndSitesRepository> CustomerAndSites
    {
        get { return CustomerAndSites; }
    }
```

However when i try to pass the collection to the view in the controller like,

```
public ViewResult List([DefaultValue(1)] int page)
    {

        var customersWithSitesToShow = customersAndSitesRepository.CustomerAndSites;
        var viewModel = new CustomerSitesListViewModel
        {                
            Customers = customersWithSitesToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = customersWithSitesToShow.Count()
            }
        };

        return View(viewModel);  //Passed to view as ViewData.Model (or simply model)
    }
```

I get a conversion error re convreting the repostiory to the view model

```
Cannot implicitly convert type  'System.Collections.Generic.List<CustomerDatabase.Domain.Abstract.ICustomersAndSitesRepository>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CustomerDatabase.WebUI.Models.CustomerViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Im defining the viewmodel like

public IEnumerable Customers { get; set; }

Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a `Customer` has many `CustomerSite` then you'd return an `IQueryable<Customer>` but use `.Include` to return the `CustomerSites` within each `Customer`.

e.g.

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomersAndSites()
{
    return MyEntities.Customers.Include("CustomerSite");
}
```

Comment: thanks im trying to implement this, but the .Include throws an error stating its not defined in the customer entity, is there a name space required for the .Include to work?

Comment: @Liam, you should just need to add `using System.Linq;` and maybe `using System.Data.Entity;`. However, make sure that you spell the Include entity right as this is the relationship shown in the EDMX rather than the table name. If it's a many-to-many relationship then it will probably be CustomerSites.

Comment: @Liam, also make sure you have `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` specified in your connection string for your Entities in your `web.config`.

Comment: hi thanks, however i already have the Linq namespace in the controller, the data.entity one doesnt seem to show, also when i add MultipleActiveResultSets=True to the conn string its states that the attribute is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

What about returning a an IQuerable custom interface containing properties for each collection you require?

```
public interface ICustomersAndSites
{
  IQueryable<CustomerSite> CustomerSites{get;}
  IQueryable<Customers> Customers{get;}
}
```

You can then set this in your repository:

```
public IQueryable<ICustomersAndSites> CustomerAndSites
    {
        get { return combinationObject; }
    }
```

Comment: thanks appreciate your advice, im trying to implement this but cant get it working, i have updated the question.